# broadcast receiver won't receive camera event

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I'm trying to make an app that detects when a user takes a photo. I set up a broadcast receiver class and registered it in the manifest file by:

```
<receiver android:name="photoReceiver" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE"/>
      <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
 </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

No matter what I try to do the program won't receive the broadcast. Here is my receiver class:

```
public class photoReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  private static final String TAG = "photoReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    CharSequence text = "caught it";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
    Log.d(TAG, "Received new photo");

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
 }
}
```

If I remove the mimeType line in the manifest and in my activity I send my own broadcast using

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

then I successfully receive the broadcast and can see the log and toast window. Am I approaching this the right way? Is there any thing that I need to add?

Comment: Where did you get `com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE` from?  From what I can tell after a quick look round the sdk, that action doesn't exist.

Comment: @sugarynugs I found it on some other threads. Here is one of them, apparently its from the source of the camera. stackoverflow.com/questions/3015448/…, when a picture is taken it calls sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE", mLastContentUri));

Comment: what version of android are you testing this on?

Comment: @sugarynugs I'm testing it right on my  HTC Evo with Froyo(2.2). I also tested it on the emulator on 2.2 with no luck. I've been trying a lot of different things like registering the receiver programmatically and still no luck. Is there a different way that you know of that I can track when a picture was taken in the background? I want my app to stay in the background and listen for the event. The only other thing I can think of would be setting up a mediastore receiver and listening for images being saved from the camera, but that would be much more of a hastle! Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: @sugarynugs Also, I am wondering if HTC's Sense could somehow change the way the camera would broadcast, but even if this was the case it should be working on the emulator. Just a thought.

Comment: @John Trying to do the same thing. Just because the default camera app sends a broadcast when a picture is taken, it doesn't mean that other camera app will send one too. At least there's a convention to save photos to "/DCIM/100MEDIA" though watching this is also unreliable.

Comment: Just what are "sugarynugs" anyway?

Comment: @siamii Is watching that directory unreliable because other directories can be used instead?  What about using the Camera.ACTION_NEW_PICTURE intent?

Answer (score 16):

I solved this but by using a different method. Instead of using a broadcast receiver I set up a fileobserver on separate folders that the camera saved to. It's not as practical as the other way, but it still works fine. Here's how I set it up:

```
FileObserver observer = new FileObserver(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/DCIM/100MEDIA") { // set up a file observer to watch this directory on sd card
            @Override
        public void onEvent(int event, String file) {
            if(event == FileObserver.CREATE && !file.equals(".probe")){ // check if its a "create" and not equal to .probe because thats created every time camera is launched
                Log.d(TAG, "File created [" + android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/DCIM/100MEDIA/" + file + "]");
                fileSaved = "New photo Saved: " + file;
            }
        }
    };
    observer.startWatching(); // start the observer
```

Comment: nice!  good to see someone who can think for themselves ;D.  I was looking at the camera source and a method `storeImage` in the `ImageCapture` class is responsible for firing of that intent.  That method only fires the intent if `!mIsImageCaptureIntent`.  I didn't look further but I would have thought that means, do the following if the image capture did not occur due to an intent.  Not sure how you are taking a picture and whether the camera app uses an intent to take a picture but food for thought.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the app **must be running in the background all the time** in order to observe the filesystem. Major problem and not playing nice.

Comment: Can you use this solution to monitor multiple folders or must you create a separate FileObserver for each folder you wish to observe?

Comment: You have to create an observer for every folder you want to monitor.

Comment: 2 years late to the party, but I tried the solution given by Tanay below and it actually works on image capture! Any objections to why I shouldn't use it?

Answer (score 11):

I sure this way works 100% . I tested carefully.

Register your broadcast receiver in AndroidManifest. Most of answers above miss 
 "category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" . BroadcastReceiver can't start without this

```
  <receiver
    android:name=".CameraReciver"
    android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE" />
            <action android:name="android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And finally, you create a class named "CameraReciver.java" extend from BroadcastReceiver
and this my code :

```
public class CameraReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("INFO", "Enter BroadcastReceiver");



Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(intent.getData(),
                null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String image_path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_data"));
        Toast.makeText(context, "New Photo is Saved as : " + image_path, 1000)
                .show();



}
```

After that, deploy your project to Emulator ( I use  genymotion),of course nothing happened because your BroadCastReceiver works without GUI. Let you open camera app, and click capture button. If everything OK, you'll get a toast with content like "New Photo is Saved as : storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20140308.jpg". Let enjoy ^_^

Thanks "tanay khandelwal" (answered above) for how to get the path of new Photo captured by camera ^_^

Hope to help everyone

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't helped me. I also asked the question about this. Here is my work.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989221/how-to-get-camera-click-event-with-the-help-of-broadcast-receiver

Comment: Above code works perfect for photos captured, any idea how we can get receiver for videos captured?

Comment: I am using camera in my app. will I get toast if the user has taken the picture( and has been taken to Save/Discard screen)?

Comment: From android 7.0, this has stopped working :( . Is there any workaround??

Answer (score 9):

you should check out here:
[ImageTableObserver](https://code.google.com/p/picasaphotouploader/source/browse/trunk/src/com/android/picasaphotouploader/ImageTableObserver.java) and here [PicasaPhotoUploader](https://code.google.com/p/picasaphotouploader/source/browse/trunk/src/com/android/picasaphotouploader/PicasaPhotoUploader.java?r=4)
how they do it.

Basically, they have an observer for `Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` that will notify of whatever happens on the SD card, then in the Observer, they check if the data returned is a photo.

```
camera = new ImageTableObserver(new Handler(), this, queue);
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, true, camera);
```

At least this way you don't have to hardcode the directory.

Answer (score 7):

Hello friends I was also trying to implement some task on capture event and after studying and working on it I prepared this code which is working fine so it may help you

first create a receiver for your event say CameraEventReciver and in that you can implement your code I m also giving you the path of the new image so it will be more useful to you for your code

```
    public class CameraEventReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(intent.getData(),      null,null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String image_path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_data"));
    Toast.makeText(context, "New Photo is Saved as : -" + image_path, 1000).show();
      }
    }
```

And in Android Manifest you just have to take some permissions and register your reciever with intent filter and appropriate action for image capture also make your receiver android enabled

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

   <receiver
        android:name="com.android.application.CameraEventReciver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: I tried it, but not working for me ... Here is my question which I asked, please help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989221/how-to-get-camera-click-event-with-the-help-of-broadcast-receiver

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that, you've put the constant name with package into apostrophes (as string). The actual string constant has different value.