# Android camera intent and get the pic from the camera

Tags: android

i have a question trouble me very long,in my app  i using a built-in  camera, i want to take a pic.if i am only a common activity i can use:

```
 Intent intent = new 
 Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

 startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

// ...

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int   resultCode, Intent data) {

if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 0) {
String result = data.toURI();

 }
}
```

because my app have Nested many layer,my takepic activity at one tab of tabactivity of tabactivity.so onActivityResult cannot get any value. so i want to use broadcast to get the pic but in the built-in  camera app,i cannot write code to send broadcast. so my question how to get the pic not use onActivityResult methods.thank you

Edit：solved  [broadcast receiver won't receive camera event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571461/broadcast-receiver-wont-receive-camera-event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider showing the camera inside a view in your app and bypassing the standard camera app entirely.  If you're curious about doing this, here are some good resources to get you started:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html
- http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html

Comment: thank you,but my app have custom a  camera app,i give people to choice one is my camera app,one is built-in.if can i  receive broadcast about the  change of pic save location ?

Comment: @pengwang I see.  Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571461/broadcast-receiver-wont-receive-camera-event