# Upload files to server using service in android

Tags: android

I have a folder in which i store images....So what i want to do is upload this images to server and once the upload is complete i want to delete this images.. This uploading and deleting should happen in background...So i have created a service that works fine..What i want is whenever a new file comes in this folder it should automatically upload..i.e the service should automatically start itself...Is there any way to do this...??

```
public class MyServices extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Started",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        sendfile();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Stopped",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

the sendfile() scans the folder and sends the images....So do i have to keep on calling this method infinitely or is there any other way???

Comment: You can use an alarm to trigger this method every few minutes; see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: Try using a FileObserver , an example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571461/broadcast-receiver-wont-receive-camera-event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and sometimes run your service and check the folder. (But be aware of battery cunsuming app =) ).

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few options:

1. You could use a [FileObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html) to watch the directory for changes.
2. If your app is creating the images, you could call startService each time a new image is added.
3. You could listen for [ACTION_NEW_PICTURE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#ACTION_NEW_PICTURE) to know when new pictures are added (assuming the app adding the pictures behaves like the camera app).

Answer (score 0):

> ..So what i want to do is upload this images to server and once the upload is complete i want to delete this images.. This uploading and deleting should happen in background...

This Github library exactly does that -
https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service  2.3K stars Apr 2020

[image]

"
-Easily upload files (Multipart/Binary/FTP out of the box) in the background with progress indication notification

-upload files to a server with FTP, HTTP multipart/form-data or binary requests

-handle multiple concurrent uploads in the background, even if the device is idle (Doze mode)

-automatically retry failed uploads, with a configurable exponential backoff
possibility to automatically delete uploaded files when the upload is successful

**Apps and libraries powered by this library-**

-JIRA Cloud

-Quora

...

"