# Android broadcast receiver not receiving Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE

Tags: android, android-intent, media

My Android app has registered for Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE but it is not receiving this intent after a photo has been taken with the stock camera app.  Is there anything else I need to do in order to receive this intent?  I have tried setting the priority to Integer.MAX_VALUE but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: What makes you think that this will be broadcast by any camera app, let alone whichever one of those you think is the "stock camera app"? Apps are welcome to use `MediaScannerConnection` to trigger an update of the `MediaStore` instead of broadcasting this `Intent`.

Comment: I tried Camera.ACTION_NEW_PICTURE and that didn't work either.  MediaScannerConnection is the next one I am going to try.

Comment: This solution seems to work out so far:  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571461/broadcast-receiver-wont-receive-camera-event

See the answer that makes use of a FileObserver.  I will still look into the MediaScannerConnection though.