# Get notification when user saves new photo in gallery

Tags: java, android

Idea of app: it is something like Google Photos.

App which listens when user take a photo with his camera app, and send this photo to server.

How can we know when user take a photo? I think that it is something like Listener "onUserTookPhotoListener", isn't it?

Infinity cycle checking gallery on background?

Comment: Please Egor read the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask guidelines otherwise no one can help you with this kind of question.

Comment: Yes, may be this changing of title is better then mine one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FileObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html). It works for files and directories. You will need to implement service though.

Please take a look at questions and answers that can be helpful:

- [First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265906/how-do-you-implement-a-fileobserver-from-an-android-service)
- [Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571461/broadcast-receiver-wont-receive-camera-event)

Comment: Thank you! But I got some issues: 
1) FileObserver works nonstandable. It can miss new photos with chance 50%. Moreover, it works with long delay, above 20 seconds.
2) Broadcast Receiver... It is not working since Android 7.
May be we should use C++ language instead of Java?